# 2 Dimensional Array Transformation

Tags: arrays, ruby

This is my array:

[[0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]]

for which I would like the '0' cells immediately above, below, to the right and left of the 1's to change into 1's as well.

The expected output would be:

0100
1111
0111
0001

However, with my code:

```
class Image
  def initialize(image)
    @image = image
  end

  def output_image
    @image.map do |image|
      puts image.join('')
    end
  end

  def blur
    find_ones.each do |x, y|
      blur_cell x, y
    end
  end

  def find_ones
    ones = []
    @image.each_with_index do |row, y|
      row.each_with_index do |cell, x|
        ones << [x, y] if cell == 1
      end
    end
    ones
  end

  def blur_cell(x, y)
    write_cell x + 1, y, 1
    write_cell x - 1, y, 1
    write_cell x, y + 1, 1
    write_cell x, y - 1, 1
  end

  def write_cell(x, y, value)
    return nil unless y > 0 && y < @image.length
    return nil unless x > 0 && x < @image[0].length
    @image[y][x] = value
  end
end

image = Image.new([
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
])

image.blur
image.output_image
```

I am getting this output:

0000
 
0111
0111
 
0001

Any help with pointing me to where my error is or any advice on how to fix it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

**Errors in Your Code**

Your code had a few small errors. Below is the corrected code. Compare that with your original code, line-by-line, and you'll see the errors and how I've fixed them. I've also made a few simplifications.

```
class Image
  def initialize(image)
    @image = image
  end

  def output_image
    @image.map do |image|
      puts image.join('')
    end
  end

 def blur
    find_ones.each do |x, y|
      blur_cell x, y
    end
  end

  def find_ones
    ones = []
    @image.each_with_index do |row, x|
      row.each_with_index do |cell, y|
        ones << [x, y] if cell == 1
      end
    end
    ones
  end
```

```
  def blur_cell(x, y)
    write_cell x + 1, y
    write_cell x - 1, y
    write_cell x, y + 1
    write_cell x, y - 1
  end

  def write_cell(x, y)
    return unless y >= 0 && y < @image.length
    return unless x >= 0 && x < @image[0].length
    @image[x][y] = 1  # was reversed
  end
end

image = Image.new([
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
])
```

```
image.blur
image.output_image
  #=> 0100
  #   1111
  #   0111
  #   0001
```

**Suggested alternative**

Here's another way of doing that.

```
def convert(arr)
  return [] if arr.empty?
  nbr_rows = arr.size
  nbr_cols = arr.first.size
  a = container(arr)
  (1..nbr_rows).
    each_with_object(Array.new(nbr_rows) { Array.new(nbr_cols) }) { |i,b|
      (1..nbr_cols).each { |j|
        b[i-1][j-1] = [a[i][j], a[i][j-1], a[i][j+1], a[i-1][j], a[i+1][j]].max } }
end

def container(arr)
  nbr_rows = arr.size
  nbr_cols = arr.first.size
  Array.new(nbr_rows+2) { |i|
    Array.new(nbr_cols+2) { |j| (i.zero? || i==nbr_rows+1 || j.zero? ||
      j==nbr_cols+1) ? 0 : arr[i-1][j-1] } }
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

convert arr
  #=> [[0, 1, 0, 0],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

**Explanation**

First observe that an element that equals 0 is set to 1 if the element above, below, left or right equals 1. For elements that are not in the first or last row or first or last column, the calculation is straightforward. One way of dealing with elements on the perimeter is construct a second array that starts with the original array and adds rows of zeros before and aft, and rows of zeros to the left and right. Computations are then made for all elements other than the perimeter rows and columns. Lastly, the first and last rows and first and last columns are stripped away. That's what I've done,

The steps are as follows for the array used in the example. First consider the method `container`.

```
nbr_rows = arr.size
  #=> 4 
nbr_cols = arr.first.size
  #=> 4 
Array.new(nbr_rows+2) { |i|
  Array.new(nbr_cols+2) { |j| (i.zero? || i==nbr_rows+1 || j.zero? ||
    j==nbr_cols+1) ? 0 : arr[i-1][j-1] } }
  #=> Array.new(6) { |i|
  #     Array.new(6) { |j| (i.zero? || i==5 || j.zero? ||
  #       j==5) ? 0 : arr[i-1][j-1] } }
  #=> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Notice that this array is `arr` sandwiched between two rows of zeroes and two columns of zeroes.

Now let's step through `convert`.

```
arr.empty?
  #=> false, so we do not return []
nbr_rows = arr.size
  #=> 4 
nbr_cols = arr.first.size
  #=> 4 
a = container(arr)
  #=> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]     
(1..nbr_rows).each_with_object(Array.new(nbr_rows) { Array.new(nbr_cols) }) { |i,b|
  (1..nbr_cols).each { |j|
    b[i-1][j-1] = [a[i][j], a[i][j-1], a[i][j+1], a[i-1][j], a[i+1][j]].max } }
  #=> (1..4).each_with_object(Array.new(4) { [0,0,0,0] }) { |i,b|
  #     (1..4).each { |j|
  #       b[i-1][j-1] = [a[i][j], a[i][j-1], a[i][j+1], a[i-1][j], a[i+1][j]].max } }
  #=> [[0, 1, 0, 0],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

For readers unfamiliar with [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), the last expression is effectively the same as the following three lines.

```
b = Array.new(nbr_rows) { Array.new(nbr_cols) }
(1..nbr_rows).each { |i|
  (1..nbr_cols).each { |j|
    b[i-1][j-1] = [a[i][j], a[i][j-1], a[i][j+1], a[i-1][j], a[i+1][j]].max } }
b
```

Comment: Cary thank you so much for your help! I'm glad to see my errors were small and that there wasn't something huge I wasn't understanding. Thank you for giving me that peace of mind! The alternative also makes a lot of sense. I'm still learning my way around different methods, especially when it comes to arrays. Again, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I suggest you post your repaired code at SO's sister-site, [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There you will get helpful suggestions for improving it. (Code Review requires working code.)

Answer (score 1):

For a Ruby solution, please see @CarySwoveland's answer.

Since your class is called `Image` and your method name is `blur_cell`, you might want to check [Image Magick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and [MiniMagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick).

The transformation you're looking for is called ["diamond dilation"](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#diamond).

With ImageMagick, it's as easy as :

```
convert matrix.png -morphology Dilate Diamond dilated_matrix.png
```

It converts

[image: matrix.png]

to

[image: dilated_matrix.png]

To convert a matrix to bitmap and vice-versa, you can use 
this [gem](https://github.com/stomar/pnm) to read and write `.pbm` files.

Comment: Doesn't that just work for bit-maps? I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Your solution is good already, I didn't want to reinvent the wheel. If the OP is already working with bitmaps, he might not need Ruby at all. I added a link for conversion between matrix and bitmap.